# Why the imageview's width and height is smaller than the drawable's width and height?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm testing `ImageView`'s function while I comes across the questions.
  I have a image which is 1000*562.My testing device is Samsung I9103, the screen size of which is 480*800.My project layout is quite simple,just an `ImageView`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/test1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/pic_1000_562"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I use the code below to get the drawable and `ImageView` size

```
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test1);
    Log.v("Testresult","width= "+imageView.getWidth()+" height= "
    +imageView.getHeight());
    Log.v("Testresult","drawawidth= "+imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()+
            " drawableheight= "
    +imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height());
}
```

But I get

```
11-17 17:48:46.865: V/Testresult(15225): width= 480 height= 690
11-17 17:48:46.865: V/Testresult(15225): drawawidth= 1000 drawableheight= 562
```

My question is why is drawabldwidth is 1000 not 480,as the image must have been scaled to fit the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `ImageView` takes the whole screen so it will take the resolution of the device. This part is clear, I guess.

As for the drawable, regardless of the `ImageView` size, it will get the same drawable and its size that you have in your resources. It doesn't matter that the `ImageView` is smaller, drawable is still the same.

---

To get the scaled image's dimensions, you can get the horizontal and vertical scale:

- horizontal: 480 / 1000 = 0.48
- vertical: 562 / 800 = 0.7025

The image will be scaled by the lower value (0.48 in this case). So the scaled dimentions are:

- horizontal: 1000 * 0.48 = 480
- vertical: 562 * 0.48 = 269.76

Comment: As I can see that the picture width fits parent（480）,and the height also scaled to about (269.76)keep the original ratio.Then how can I get the scaled picture size(480*269.76)?

Comment: I guess you can check if it will be scaled horizontally or vertically (which scale is smaller) and then get the other one.